# Wordpress browser cache

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Users of my woocommerce website always see the old css and i constantly have to tell them to refresh the page.  I haven't got any wordpress cache installed?  Is there a method or plugin in wordpress that can clear the cache so my changes are seen immediately?  I'm using woocommerce 2.3.7

Comment: Have you installed any plugins for caching or for speed? Have you configure them properly?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/ it can automatically purge cache after the number of seconds you set in settings. it will surely help you.

Comment: If you use Google Chrome you can download a plugin called Cache Killer (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en)

Comment: @Dave isn't it good to use cache plugin in website rather then user to install cache killer in every system? read the question carefully

Comment: @Noman it was a supportive comment to help with development and not an answer, if it was an answer I would have put it as an answer.

Comment: @Noman with w3-total-cache, would i enable the browser cache and add a time limit to the browser cache?

Comment: yes you can enable browser cache and limit to cache.